# Push-to-open pantry door latch stuck closed

Tags: doors, stuck

Push to open latch on pantry door is stuck. The magnet spring is at bottom corner, on the other side from hinges. There is a push plate at normal height, but no handles or knobs, nothing to grab.

Comment: Please post a picture of your door. Use the Mountain icon in the Edit link to post the picture.

Comment: There's no door edge anywhere that you can grab? Nothing to get a fingernail or screwdriver behind to pop the door open?

Comment: 'Tis the season of humidy induced wood swelling.